# How to use django-tracker?

Tags: python, django

Is anyone know how to use django-tracker? Where I can find some more details about how to use django-tracker?

Comment: @laundroMat django-tracking is different from django-tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tracker

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/frankwiles/django-app-metrics instead.