# Where I can download django-tracker?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use django-tracker ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618876/how-to-use-django-tracker)

Is anyone know where I can download django-tracker  and the module from tracker.models import Tracker?

I mean this django-tracker http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tracker/0.0.1.

Comment: -1: A Google search turns up numerous "Django Tracker" hits.  The question is too vague to answer.  Please be much, much more specific on which exact "tracker" is required.  If possible, use Google  and provide the link as part of the question.

Comment: Don't repost the same question within one hour - this is RUDE

Answer (score 0):

As you are being rather vague I'll assume that you mean this one here:

http://code.google.com/p/django-tracking/

I hope this helps.